# How can I format phone numbers in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: formatting

I'm wanting to format a column in SharePoint 2013 to automatically enter the parentheses and dashes in a phone number.

So no matter how the telephone is entered, it shows (###) ###-####.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: How do users enter data? default list forms or custom forms? Your question is only about formatting? does that mean if you implemented the logic already to check for valid phone number already?

Answer (score 3):

Create a calculated column and use this formula:

```
TEXT([Phone number],"(000)-000-0000")
```

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/ffd7fdde-52f8-4bc7-a3f5-e4102d36fe2e/calculated-column-to-format-phone-number

Answer (score 0):

There are a few approaches you could take for this.  As far as I know there is nothing that automatically formats phone numbers to a default `(###) ###-####` like you are looking for.

- To do this you could use column validation for the field.  This wouldn't allow a user to input something unless it followed your format.
- Another option would be to craft some sort of calculated field to take the input and format it the desired way.  With this you may have to try and take into account a user could input the value different ways (i.e. `###.###.####`, `1-###-###-####`, `###-###-####`, etc.)
- The third option would be similar to a calculated field as for the formatting but could be done using a workflow.  Again you would have to take into account the varied ways users could input a phone number.

I think I would lean towards creating a calculated field and try to catch the most common ways a user would input a phone number.  Any approach should work, but none of the options work flawlessly.